# How to get record count of an array of objects in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to display the total number of records returned from my mongo 3.4 database.  For this particular query, the results should be 380 but it's showing 14489.  I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing / forgetting about PHP

Here's the code: (including some debug statements about the type of variable I'm dealing with)

```
       $numrecords = count($records);                                
       echo"<BR><font color=red>".gettype($records)."</font>";
       echo"<BR><font color=red>".sizeof($records)."</font>";
       if (  $numrecords > 0 ) {
              echo "<tr><td colspan='5'><h3>Record Count: ".$numrecords ."</h3></td></tr>";
              echo "<tr><th>PH Number</th><th>Department</th></tr>";
              foreach ( $records as $rec ) {
                     if (!empty($rec->department)) {                                                                                          
                         echo "<tr>";
                         echo "<td>". $rec->phnum . "</td>";
                         echo "<td>". $rec->department . "</td>";
                         echo "</tr>";
                     }   
              } //end for 
       } else {
              echo "<tr><td colspan='5'>No matching data</td></tr>";                                  
       }
```

It says the object type is 'array'.  I've been playing with count() vs. sizeof()

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Verify the your mongodb query you have in PHP, it is returning the numbers of documents you are expected?, use some DBMS (http://genghisapp.com) or do it using commands.

Comment: Where's the query - have you messed up a JOIN? What you're showing here is how `$records` is being processed not how it was generated in the first place, which would probably be helpful.

Comment: @YulioAlemanJimenez the query is correct because the results that are displayed as I iterate through them all are the ones  I'm looking for.  And... I copy and paste the table I make with the results into notepad, and I have 380 rows.

Comment: Please show the source query and code providing `$records`. It it's is a valid [Cursor](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php) then you might even try forcing to an array with [`toArray()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-cursor.toarray.php) to be certain. But show the code if unsure.

Answer (score -1):

So it shows the correct number of rows in the table, but the count shows more than what's in the displayed table?

Try to use msqli_num_rows after your query

Here's an example below, you'll have to change it to your needs since you didn't provide your query code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE datarow='$datarow'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
//this is where you count the number of rows returned from this query.
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

If this doesn't work, there's a problem with your query not meeting the specifications that you desire.

Comment: is this applicable to a mongo db?

Comment: @sicksixstrings mysqli_num_rows is used to count numbers of results with MySQLi, It is not applicable to a mongodb!

Comment: @dot you may want to check this link http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.count.php